# How to split nested column data and format it as a new row?

Tags: sql-server

Each `rabat_po_proizvodu` is fetched in a string format `10.0;20;30`, how to split it for each row?

```
declare @brojStavke int = 1;
 
declare cursor_stavke cursor
    for select right(replicate(' ', 4) + rtrim(rbr), 4),
    art_sif0, kolicina, r.value as rabat_po_proizvodu from
    [SERVER-DELL].ZaObuku.[dbo].carts, STRING_SPLIT(@rabati,';') r where cart_ID = @Cart_Id
open cursor_stavke;
fetch next from cursor_stavke into @rbr, @art_sif, @kolicina, @rabat_po_proizvodu;
while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin

set @brojStavke = @brojStavke + 1;
```

so that the ending result has this format

```
art_sif0 | kolicina | cart_ID | rabat_po_proizvodu
                        10            10.0
                        10            20
                        10            30
```

Comment: take a look at [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: `select null as atr_sif0,null as kolicina,10 as cart_ID,value as rabat_po_proizvodu from string_split('10.0;20;30',';')`

Comment: Meaningful sample data and expected results will help us help you here, if I am honest.